# Horizontal menu that changes on page location

Tags: jquery, css, menu, horizontallist

I have a horizontal sticky menu on my site which is a single long page.  The menu scrolls the user to the different sections of the page.

[www.dyhas.com](http://www.dyhas.com) (scroll down to menu)

My question: is there a way I can make the buttons change color and stay "white" when the user clicks the menu item to a section.  Or, is there a way that I can make the menu dynamically change when the user scrolls to a new section?

For example, if the user scrolls to "overview" or clicks "overview" the li box with "overview" will turn white and stay white.  When the user "clicks" Health or scrolls to the "health" section the menu will change to that the Health li is white and remains white while in that section?

Is there already a jquery menu out there that does something like that?  I did a search but came up short.

Comment: Hi, what you are looking for is sticky menus done by jQuery. Just google it. Sticky Menus and something should come up. I have got this for one of my customers. I will check and the post the code here, but meanwhile, just google it.

Comment: Hi Mee, I already have the sticky menu on the site.  I'm now wanting the ul items inside of the menu to recognize where they are on the page and change background colors accordingly.  Does Sticky menus do that as well?  I don't remember reading that on the sticky menu site.

Comment: Check out [Bootstrap Scrollspy](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy) or [visualNav](http://mottie.github.io/visualNav/index.html).

Comment: @JamieCollingwood yah they do. All you need to do is add those properties to the Css of each class you got.

Comment: @JamieCollingwood what you need is a class like `ul > li: active {code}` also there is `ul > li .selected{code}`. Have you had a try? Also, you will have to have a javascript to recognize that it is selected.

Comment: I was able to use waypoints to do what I needed.  Thanks for the suggestion.